# How to bind of parent class property in child class xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, datagrid

I have the following inheritance hierarchy. Scoda class extens from Car class. Car has a property named color and Scoda has a proprty named speed. In main window i created a data grid which is binded to the list of Car class. When button is clicked, i change the color and speed property of the object in the current list. Speed property is changing but color property is not changing. Binding is not working for the parent class proprty. How to solve this ?

**Car.cs**

```
public class Car : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string color { get; set; }
    public string Color { get { return color; } set { color = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Color)); } }


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    }
```

**Scoda.cs**

```
public class Scoda : Car, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Scoda(int speed)
    {
        this.Speed = speed;
    }

    private int speed { get; set; }
    public int Speed { get { return speed; } set { speed = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Speed)); } }


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid  Grid.Row="0" x:Name="carGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding CarList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        SelectionMode="Single" Margin="10,10,0,0" SelectionUnit="FullRow" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True">

        <DataGrid.Columns >
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Speed" Binding="{Binding Path=Speed}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Color" Binding="{Binding Path=Color}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click">CLICK ME</Button>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<Car> carList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Car> CarList { get { return carList; } set { carList = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CarList)); } }



    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        CarList = new ObservableCollection<Car>();

        Car car = new Scoda(150);
        CarList.Add(car);
       
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Scoda car in CarList) {
            car.Speed = 120;
            car.Color = "Red";
        }
    }

     protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
     {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }
    }
```

Comment: Does that even compile? Duplicate `PropertyChanged`.

Comment: It should be `public class Scoda : Car { ... }`. The derived class Scoda would then implement because the base class Car does. Do not declare PropertyChanged and OnPropertyChanged again.

Comment: Yes it is compiled

Comment: Also for the overall idea. Do you assume that only Skodas have a "speed", and cars in general do not? Better add a `Brand` property to the Car class, and if you want to play around with class inheritance, declare a `Truck` class or `Limousine` or something similar.

Comment: The code above is just for example, but in my real code both parent and child classes should declare PropertyChanged. Because i have linqtosql classes and those classes declare PropertyChanged  default. Which way should i follow if both classes must declare ?

Comment: It seems also pointless to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the MainWindow class, because the CarList property is only set in the constructor. So remove the interface implementation, and declare a read-only auto-implemented property, like `public ObservableCollection<Car> CarList { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Car>();`

Comment: "*both parent and child classes should declare PropertyChanged*" - no, they should not. If a base class implements an interface, the derived class automatically does that too.

Comment: I’m surprised that compiled then.  I recommend you get ReSharper quick smart!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Scoda` implementation hides the `PropertyChanged` and `OnPropertyChanged` members of the `Car` base class.

Remove them from the derived class and your example works as expected.

`speed` should be a field, not a property though:

```
public class Scoda : Car
{
    public Scoda(int speed)
    {
        this.Speed = speed;
    }

    private int speed;
    public int Speed
    { 
        get { return speed; }
        set { speed = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Speed)); }
    }
}
```